# Chrome devtools run snippet to load pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, code-snippets

### What i would like to achieve

Using **Chrome Canary 65** i would like to use a chrome snippet to load several pages of a website and
for each page

1. **done:** get certain urls
2. **done:** get timing-values via `window.performance.timing`
3. **done:** create a query string that contains the timing-values  (for example `?page=home&loadTime=200&domcontentloaded=500`)
4. **done:** reload the same page including the querystring `window.location.href = url + queryString`
5. **fail:** go to the next page

You can find my [current code at this gist](https://gist.github.com/surfmuggle/01577e5987e236ea46e250ed57d60029)

### What i tried

This is my code and see also [my codepen mock](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OOYwpE?editors=1111)

```
function testPageLoadTimes()
{
   // step 1  get [] of urls / href-values done
   var linkList = getMainNavigationLinks() 

   // step 2 get timings done
   var timings = getPerformanceTimings();

   // step 3 craft query string done
   let querystring = getQuerystring(timings);        
     
   // for each link / url do the following fail
   for (var link of linkList) 
   {
       if(document.readyState === 'complete')
       {               
           // let timings = getPerformanceTimings();
           // let querystring = getQuerystring(timings);        
           // fail
           setTimeout(function()
                      {
                          window.location.href=link + querystring}
                       ,6000);
     }
   }  
}
```

I also tried a recursive approach

```
function testPage(linkList)
{      
  console.log("link", linkList[0]);        
  if(document.readyState === 'complete')
  {
       
        let timings = getPerformanceTimings();
        let querystring = getQuerystring(timings); 
        let newUrl = linkList[0]+ querystring;               
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log(newUrl);
            console.time();
            window.location.href=newUrl;
        },2000);
  }    
  linkList.splice(0, 1);
  testPage(linkList);
}

var linkList = getMainNavigationLinks();
testPage(linkList);
```

Since i am inexperienced with promises i was unable to make something work using a promise

```
function loadPage(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {        
    resolve(console.log("foo resolve"));
    reject(console.log("foo reject"));    
  });
}
```

### Question

How can i use a chrome snippet to load the same page and after it has loaded go to the next page?

See [my mock on codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OOYwpE?editors=1111)

### Edit

Step 4 is working now using

```
    let newUrl = window.location.href 
                       + "?page=" + window.location.pathname 
                                  +"&" + querystring;               
    console.log("newUrl", newUrl);  
    window.location.href=newUrl;
```

Step 5 go to the next page is still unclear

Comment: when you navigate to a different URL, the entire current execution context is destroyed so timeouts/callbacks in your code won't run.

Comment: In my chrome-canary 65 using experimental flag i have a setting under console `selected context only` i would assume that this enables me to keep the context?

Comment: Why? It's a console setting to show messages from the current context.

Comment: If this approach is not feasible do you have another idea how i could achieve to run a snippet after the next page has loaded?

Comment: Snippets can't do that. Only a chrome extension can. Also you can write a userscript in Tampermonkey - it'll be automatically re-executed after navigation and you can save/read the state using localStorage or GM_setValue/GM_getValue.